# Database android

Tags: android, mysql

I have a database in phpmyadmin that I query using the command

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
```

Now put the result in a TextView in this way:

```
TextView resLayout = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.res);

String res = sendQuery.send("SELECT * FROM contact");

resLayout.append(res);
```

If I wanted to analyze the contents of my database or know the contents of each row as I do?
For example:

```
[{"Name":"David","Surname":"Beckham","id":"1"}]
```

how do I know the content of "Name" and obtain as a result of "David"?

It is online database.

Answer (score 0):

Create an object that describes the result of your query. For example:

```
public class Person {
    String name;
    String Surname;
    int id;
}
```

And assign the returned values to `Person`.
Than use this object for your needs.

Comment: but if i have more row?

Comment: If you have more than one row, keep the data in List<Person> or Map<int, Person> (int should be id), depends on your needs.

Comment: where can I find some examples?